# Do the Datastore Query is relying on a web session or some thread of execution?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to know if the Datastore Query web safe cursor is related to any web session or some thread of execution?, from the example:

```
public class ListPeopleServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                   throws ServletException, IOException {

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.getWriter().println("<ul>");

    int pageSize = 15;
    FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(pageSize);
    String startCursor = req.getParameter("cursor");

    // If this servlet is passed a cursor parameter, let's use it
    if (startCursor != null) {
      fetchOptions.startCursor(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(startCursor));
    }

    Query q = new Query("Person");
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

    QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
    for (Entity entity : results) {
      resp.getWriter().println("<li>" + entity.getProperty("name") + "</li>");
    }
    resp.getWriter().println("</ul>");

    String cursorString = results.getCursor().toWebSafeString();

    // Assuming this servlet lives at '/people'
    resp.getWriter().println(
      "<a href='/people?cursor=" + cursorString + "'>Next page</a>");
  }
}
```

I am asking this for the reason to know if on a Restful service where each Request is unique an no session is active at all, will the web safe String will still be accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor is just a pointer to some location in the index. It's not related to any web session or some execution thread. You can use it safely on multiple threads or different user sessions.